# No filter_path option on Elasticsearch-python bulk helper API

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Responses from the **_index** and **_bulk** APIs contain quite a bit of information. This information can be useful for troubleshooting requests or for implementing retry logic but can use considerable bandwidth. In this example, indexing a 32-byte document results in a 339-byte response (including headers):

If we update/index a document like below,

```
PUT elasticsearch_domain/more-movies/_doc/1
{"title": "Back to the Future"}
```

It'll return a response like below,

```
{
  "_index": "more-movies",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 4,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 3,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

Now if we use **filter_path** with our existing indexing process using `_bulk` API

```
PUT elasticsearch_domain/more-movies/_doc/1?filter_path=result,_shards.total
{"title": "Back to the Future"}
```

Then Response will be like,

```
{
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2
  }
}
```

*So my question is how to use **filter_path** to filter out the response with [Elasticsearch-python bulk API](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) or streaming bulk API?*

Comment: Have you tried to set it when you call the search? Something like this `response = es.search(index="index", filter_path=["hits.hits.result","hits.hits._shards.total"], body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})` ?

Comment: @leandrojmp thanks for the reply, I don't want to filter it on **search** documents, I want it on while using **bulk** indexing

Comment: You can try to apply filter_path the same way to bulk. try it out

Comment: On kibana it works with *_bulk* but confused how to do with elasticsearch-python method `elasticsearch.helpers.bulk(client, actions, stats_only=False, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way as with the search function. Try it out like this:

```
elasticsearch.helpers.bulk(client, actions, stats_only=False, filter_path=["hits.hits.result","hits.hits._shards.total"])
```

Comment: I was also thinking to use **args* for filter_path, I'll try next day and let you know the status. Thanks, sir.

Comment: Thanks @val, we are using this code `filter_path=["items.update.result", "items.update._id", "items.update.status"]` instead of `hits.hits.result` to filter out the responses with `bulk API`